# A Code to find out who called a macro attached to a shape( Dropdown in my case) in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown in an excel worksheet with an assigned macro which is written to return the dropdown name but in vain

```
Private Sub Cmb()
   'cmb is the assinged macro name

    Workbooks("Test2").Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name

End Sub
```

It is returning `the item with specified name wasn't found`

Please help me to resolve this issue. I'm a beginner in excel .So it would be grateful if a detailed explanation is included

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: Its not returning the dropdown name which i'm looking or. Sorry for the incomplete question. Edited now. Thanks!

Comment: As per Excel documentation, `Application.Caller` will not return the dropdown name, but exactly the error you get.  `Application.Caller` is defined only for some conditions, and the `Change` event is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have to get the dropdown name Is there any  way to return a dropdown(form control) name?. Thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a solution using `Screen.ActiveControl`. But somehow I can't get it to work (Excel 2010).

Comment: if cmb is an activex control rather than a forms control there is no property to return its name. since the event is specific to that control why do you need the name?

Comment: @JosieP It is a form control Combobox. A macro called Cmb in which code should be supposedly written is assigned to it. Similarly, I have many combobox in multiple sheets of same workbook which i think should be assigned to the same macro Cmb. This macro will read the range from which data need to be populated from control worksheet and populate accordingly. As my control sheet has all the combobox name and the corresponding range. I have to know the combobox name to find the right range from which data need to be populated. I hope my explanation makes sense!

Comment: then `application.caller` should work to return the name; your error could then be triggered if your macro is being called while that sheet is not active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you are assigning a Macro to Combobox, it is, for sure, a Form Control Combobox and not an activeX control. So the Application.Caller would definitely return the name of the combobox you are calling the macro from. Did you try this:

```
MsgBox "The name of the combobox is " & Application.Caller
```

Edit: After receiving the spreadsheet.

So basically : there are two Errors:

```
 Workbooks("Test2").Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
```

You don't need the above line, because when you click a Dropdown, the required sheet would always be active. The main error in your macro is coming because Test2 is not the workbook. Use Workbooks("Test2.xlsm")..........

Then we come to the next line:

You have used this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
```

Now the Name property returns a String. So you need to store that value to a Variable. The error is coming because you are not storing it in any variable. Use this:

```
Dim shpName as String

shpName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
```

Error will be removed. I have also sent you back the spreadsheet. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
V

Comment: I have tried. But it is showing the same. I dont know why his error is triggered!

Comment: Would you mind sending your spreadsheet at vikasbhandari2@gmail.com? Should be an easy fix. I need to look at your file, if possible.